# Circuit changes, what is the input high and low given when the circuit is lit and not!

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi, circuit-design

[image: This is the circuit]
One change in the circuit, the R1 is not 4300 ohms but instead 4700 ohms.
The voltmeter is the input into the raspberry pi GPIO board. What would be the input (voltage) when light gets to the phototransistor and when not?
PT0 is the ir phototransistor (my real circuit has no base, only two leads.)
For any more information please ask for clarification. Thanks

Comment: What do you think it is. And why.

Comment: I extremely appreciate you trying to get me involved and "helping me" rather than "solving it for me" but I am still a highschool grade 12 student! and I have a basic understanding of circuits as we have not even started electronics and so that is why, I absolutely have no idea how phototransistors change current and so that is why, I have no idea what would the answer be. Also, I am semi sure of how multiple branches affect the current and voltage and resistance. Sorry! But I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A phototransistor works exactly like a regular transistor would, except instead of a base powered by an input bias current, it is turned on and off by light. A NPN type phototransistor will, when lit, turn on, connecting the collector to the emitter.

R1 is a pull-up resistor. It is used to bring a node up through the pull-up resistor to a certain voltage. In this case, the node is the connection between R1 and the Phototransistor's Collector, and R2.

R2 is a series resistor. It will simply limit current flowing through it, and in this case completely optional/unnecessary.

When the phototransistor is on, as mentioned, the collector and emitter are connected in a very low resistance connection. As this is the path of least resistance compared to the high resistance of R1, the node at the Collector pin, will be pulled to it. Since the Emitter is tied to ground, that makes the node tied to ground.

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it, kind of. I will comment again, after thinking about it.