# Designing photogate for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi, phototransistor, circuit-design

### Please help:

I am building a photogate. I was looking for help in building a circuit for the Raspberry Pi 2.

### A little background:

I am still a highschool grade 12 student! and I have a basic understanding of circuits as we have not even started electronics and so that is why, I absolutely have no idea how phototransistors change current and so that is why, I have no idea what would the answer be. Also, I am semi sure of how multiple branches affect the current and voltage and resistance. Sorry! I am building this for my Physics IA. Going a little stronger. I will appreciate help or the circuit but if possible, I will appreciate any form of knowledge I can gain.

### Design objectives:

What I am looking to build is a simple circuit which has one lead going to input of the GPIO board. One lead to ground and one lead to either 3.3V or 5.0V on the GPIO board, I have no idea how to select which voltage to use. The circuit would have a ir phototransistor that when dark would give an input in raspberry pi GPIO input of 2.0 volt-3.3 volt and 0.0v-1.0 volts when light. I can use any resistor. I want to build the most basic circuit that can give me these inputs when dark and when light.
Thanks A lot. Please ask for clarification if needed.

PS. this is a question to build a circuit whereas the other question is about input values from a pre-existing circuit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circuit changes, what is the input high and low given when the circuit is lit and not!](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202982/circuit-changes-what-is-the-input-high-and-low-given-when-the-circuit-is-lit-an)

Comment: Also, all Raspberry Pi inputs are 3.3V only. Never connect 5V to a GPIO directly.

Comment: This is actually a new question, that circuit did not work and so i am trying to build a newer circuit. This time, i will have two circuits operating, one with the ir led that i can build myself as it is super simple and one with the ir phototransistor that i need help with. The phototransistor when lit will give an input of 0.0-1.0 volts at the GPIO input and 2.0-3.3 when dark.

Comment: The 3.3V vs 5.0V is the source, not the input. And i wouldn't connect a 5.0V to input. What I mean is which one should I use as the source for my circuit.

Comment: That circuit is a standard phototransistor setup. There is no reason it shouldn't work unless you didn't wire it right or the schematic you provided was wrong.

Comment: That is probably the reason and so that is why i am trying to make it a little less complex. One circuit for the led and another for the phototransistor so i dont have to deal with them together and if another problem occurs, i can narrow it to one of the circuits.

Comment: My question at its bare bones is, how do i eliminate the IR led from the last circuit? (in the last circuit, i have used a 4700 ohms resistor instead of 4300 circuit at R1)

Comment: Soo, how would I eliminate that LED

Comment: If you are using an IR phototransistor, you need an IR source, which the led is the easiest. Otherwise if you want it to work with regular light, you want a photoresistor and a regular transistor. See the answer to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96423/inverted-photocell-novice-question +Vs is the 3.3V. The led and resistor should be 10k and connected to the RPi's gpio instead.

Comment: Can't i just keep an led in a seperat circuit and use that to turn it light and dark? Keeping the IR led and The IR phototransistor but keeping led in a seperate circuit (where i can just build a seperate circuit with on off switch for led (doesn't even have to be connected to the raspberry pi))

Comment: What do you mean by separate circuit? The one you have now, with an led on one side, and the phototransistor on the other, ARE separate circuits.

Comment: The IR phototransistor but keeping led in a seperate circuit (where i can just build a seperate circuit with on off switch for led (doesn't even have to be connected to the raspberry pi))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic setup. Two "circuits". The LED can be powered by a battery or from the RPi's 5V. R-LED should be calculated for the LED you use.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f10hGI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: ahh, thank you so much! I assure you, i won't simply use the circuit but learn from it :)

Comment: I wonder if Q1 can pull the pin low enough. You may need another transistor (a normal one) to amplify the signal. Check with a voltmeter how low it goes.

Comment: If Q1 can't pull low enough, simply increase R2 (perhaps 100 kilohms)

Comment: @PauloSoares 3.3V and 10kΩ means just 0.3mA. Any common phototransistor can do that easy enough, enough to pull the GPIO node to mostly ground.

Comment: That's electronic schematic convention. Typically I would just use the ground symbol, but in this case I explicitly named it as connecting to the RPI ground. It's redundant. Just connect the emitter to ground.

Comment: I built the circuit exactly but the same thing happens as before, the code i am using is the one from the previous question?

Comment: WHEN I use BCM 2 FOR INPUT, IT GIVES ME this warning and then nothing happens: --------
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/photogate.py", line 6
    GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN)
RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=96128 and http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27500/powering-5v-fan-gpio-1-3 Ignorable warning in this case.

Comment: Ok, so i built the circuit on a bread board and it works, but I am sure I built it correctly on the circuit too but it doesn't work with the soldered circuit (it worked 1 time but then stopped again - a let down)- any tips?

Comment: Its WORKING. Yesss! After 10+ hours of fiddeling around. Thank You so much!!!